# Can you select tags from another page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I have this page a.html that has all the jquery codes. And there is another page b.html that has only html tags. Is it possible to do something like:

```
alert( $('a').fromhref('b.html').html() );
```

Basically I want to select a tag from another page. I want to basically avoid the use of iframes and httprequests.

Comment: And what do you want to *do* with the tag?

Comment: How are you going to access the page if not through http request? Magic?

Comment: @David, nothing yet, i just want to know if it can be done through jquery. Maybe jquery has its own built in code for handling httprequests that I don't want to re-write...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access parts of another page with jQuery, provided both pages are on the same domain, using `load()`, but this can only be done with an http request (though if the page is cached, it might not be necessary), as a brief example:

```
$('#idOfElementOnPageA').load('http://example.com/pageB.html #idOFElementOnPageB');
```

This will load the html of the element with an `id` of `idOfElementOnPageB` into the element with the `id` of `idOfElementOnPageA`.

But please note, this in no way avoids making a call to the server, though it does allow you to retrieve elements from another page without using `iframe` elements in your page.

References:

- [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Comment: is it possible to suppress any javascript errors caused by loading the html from that other page. Since it's not really my code (i.e. from another page) I don't care about any errors it creates.

Comment: its some microsoft sharepoint scripts thats causing 2 errors, because i'm loading an aspx page but it's on the same domain.

Answer (score -1):

The filename should be script.js instead of a.html, then, use the [script tag](http://css-tricks.com/the-script-tag/).

Basically, something like this (in b.html):

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

As long as script.js is in the same folder as b.html.

Comment: So this means that its loading a script file when really its loading an html file?

Comment: a.html only has Javascript, right? If not, move all that javascript to a seperate file called script.js.

Comment: no, I said it has all the jquery codes, not has only jquery codes.

Comment: Well, use the solution I mentioned then - move the jquery code to script.js